# Is the fact that foo(a:b, d.x) is illegal coffeescript a bug of the interpreter or part of the language?

Tags: coffeescript

in coffeescript the following code is all legal

> foo(a:b, d)
>
> foo({a:b}, d.x)
>
> foo(a:b, (d.x))

But for some reason

> foo(a:b, d.x)

is illegal. I figure this must either be because there is an ambiguity here I'm not seeing or the interpreter is being overly vigilant.

Comment: Smells like a bug to me. Wanna [open an issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/)? =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out this is a previously reported coffeescript bug